# Webpack Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am getting a few module not found errors from webpack, but the problem is the files are actually there. I've triple-checked and I am sure the files are there, but for some reason, webpack is failing to find them. Is there any way for me to find out more information on why webpack is failing?

```
ERROR in ./~/react-router/BrowserRouter.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/createBrowserHistory' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/BrowserRouter.js 11:28-67

ERROR in ./~/react-router/HashRouter.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/createHashHistory' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/HashRouter.js 11:25-61

ERROR in ./~/react-router/HashRouter.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/PathUtils' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/HashRouter.js 19:17-45

ERROR in ./~/react-router/MemoryRouter.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/createMemoryHistory' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/MemoryRouter.js 11:27-65

ERROR in ./~/react-router/LocationUtils.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/PathUtils' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/LocationUtils.js 17:17-45

ERROR in ./~/react-router/LocationUtils.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/LocationUtils' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react-router
 @ ./~/react-router/LocationUtils.js 8:21-53

ERROR in ./~/react/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fbjs/lib/memoizeStringOnly' in [MODULE_PROJECT_ROOT]\node_modules\react\lib
 @ ./~/react/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js 21:24-61
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack babel es6 giving me errors with react-router 1.0 "module not found"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979046/webpack-babel-es6-giving-me-errors-with-react-router-1-0-module-not-found)

Comment: I am using React Router 4.0.0-alpha.4 which [comes with the history module](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4/package.json) and as I mentioned above, the history files are definitely there.

Also, the last module not found is for react not react router. This makes me think this is an issue with webpack not react router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why webpack was unable to find the requested modules. I had provided an array of absolute paths to [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) and [resolveLoader.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader). What I had forgotten to do was including the default value for these fields in my arrays. In my case, I just prepended "node_modules" to these arrays of file paths and that solved my problem.